# Read Route Request Headers

Tags: ember.js

I have an emberjs app where all requests are sent through a proxy that inserts some user information into the header. In my ember app I would like to read that header data and save it as a 'current user' object for every route. I cannot find how I would get access to the route request headers.

In a node app I would do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  req.get('Content-Type');
});
```

But my emberjs route looks like this (no request variable):

```
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('dashboard');
}
```

How do I get a request object in emberjs to read the headers?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why you want the request headers and what you want to do with them?

Comment: My proxy handles all authentication and only sends authenticated users to the ember app. The header contains the user payload.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it sounds like you want to get the HTTP Headers for the initial get of the web page, which has been discussed over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

It might be easier to expose an endpoint to return  the user information

Answer (score 0):

Ember is a Single Page Application framework, so when changing routes you are not making a page request and so there are no request header associated with a route.

Comment: There must be an initial request to the app.